# enable_extension "plpgsql" not generated in schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, macos, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to ruby on rails and i'm running into little error I believed you could help me fix.

Rails could not generate `enable_extension "plpgsql"` in schema.rb

I generated model like this:

```
rails generate model CreateUsers last_name:string first_name:string birthday:date email:string password_digest:string
```

And I run `rails db:migrate`

I got this in return

```
...
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_01_21_134353) do

  create_table "create_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.date "birthdate"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

without

```
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
```

I tried dropping the table and run

```
rake db:rollback

rake db:migrate
```

Still not included in schema.rb

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad! I supposed to create new app that use postgres with the following

`rails new gurudian-main-api --database=postgresql`